# What is the best way to update column1 value from record containing max(column2)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I came up with this solution:

```
UPDATE sessions
SET time_stop = now()
WHERE time_start = (SELECT max(time_start) FROM sessions);
```

However, I have the feeling that it is not the optimal way of doing it. I would be interested in other, better ways of achieving the same result.

Thank you.

PS: if you feel there is no better way, please say so too.

Answer (score 1):

I hardly see a way to optimize this query apart from setting up an index on sessions.time_start.

Comment: If time_start is indexed, this should be pretty much instantaneous. And it handles the case of ties.